# SUM SUBQUERY MySql

Tags: mysql

I have data:

```
2020/08/01  A   17
2020/08/01  A   17
2020/08/01  A   17
2020/08/02  A   17
2020/08/02  A   17
2020/08/02  A   17
```

I want data:

```
2020/08/01  A   17
2020/08/02  A   17
```

And sum:

```
A     34
```

How to sum them?
I've tried with this query, but failed

```
SELECT
SUM((SELECT
    TotCall
FROM
    mob_distribution
    JOIN krd_slsman ON krd_slsman.wh_id = mob_distribution.Wh_id
    JOIN krd_item ON krd_item.item_id = mob_distribution.Item_id 
WHERE
    krd_slsman.wh_parn = '103' 
    AND mob_distribution.Tanggal BETWEEN "2020-09-01" 
    AND "2020-09-03" 
GROUP BY
    mob_distribution.Tanggal 
ORDER BY
    mob_distribution.Wh_id ASC )) AS K
FROM
    mob_distribution AS a
    JOIN krd_slsman ON krd_slsman.wh_id = a.Wh_id
    JOIN krd_item ON krd_item.item_id = a.Item_id 
WHERE
    krd_slsman.wh_parn = '102' 
    AND a.Tanggal BETWEEN "2020-09-01" 
    AND "2020-09-03" 
GROUP BY
    a.Wh_id 
ORDER BY
    a.Wh_id ASC
```

Comment: I don't see how your query is related to the data that you show. It's just a single table with 3 columns, but your query mentions 3 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making up names for the columns of your sample table.

```
SELECT type, SUM(num)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT date, type, num
    FROM yourTable
) AS x
GROUP BY type
```

The subquery gets rid of all the duplicate rows, then the main query sums each group.

Comment: Yessss, wonderful. Thanks bro. You safe my live. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.TotCall)
FROM
    (SELECT
        TotCall
    FROM
        mob_distribution
        JOIN krd_slsman ON krd_slsman.wh_id = mob_distribution.Wh_id
        JOIN krd_item ON krd_item.item_id = mob_distribution.Item_id 
    WHERE
        krd_slsman.wh_parn = '102' 
        AND mob_distribution.Tanggal BETWEEN "2020-09-01" 
        AND "2020-09-03" 
    GROUP BY
        mob_distribution.Tanggal 
    ORDER BY
        mob_distribution.Wh_id ASC) AS a
```

this my code, thanks Barmar

Comment: This isn't grouped by the column with `A` in it.

Comment: Yes, sir. Roger that. Thanks.